# Option importsNotUsedAsValues is deprecated

Tags: svelte

Could someone help me with this `jsonfig.json` file for a svelte project? It's saying that the `importsNotUsedAsValues` option should be replaced with `verbatimModuleSyntax`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    /**
     * svelte-preprocess cannot figure out whether you have
     * a value or a type, so tell TypeScript to enforce using
     * `import type` instead of `import` for Types.
     */
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    /**
     * To have warnings / errors of the Svelte compiler at the
     * correct position, enable source maps by default.
     */
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    /**
     * Typecheck JS in `.svelte` and `.js` files by default.
     * Disable this if you'd like to use dynamic types.
     */
    "checkJs": true
  },
  /**
   * Use global.d.ts instead of compilerOptions.types
   * to avoid limiting type declarations.
   */
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte"]
}
```

The full error message is

> Option 'importsNotUsedAsValues' is deprecated and will stop functioning in TypeScript 5.5. Specify compilerOption '"ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"' to silence this error. Use 'verbatimModuleSyntax' instead.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [verbatimModuleSyntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#verbatimModuleSyntax) instead of

```
"importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"
```

You should use

```
"verbatimModuleSyntax": true
```

See the details in the [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/52203).

Answer (score 0):

I think this resolved the issue for me:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...other compiler options here...
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",
    "preserveValueImports": false
  }
  ...rest of your config here...
}
```